# Why does this perceptron algorithm work?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, machine-learning

I am trying to understand this algorithm for perceptron, but do not understand how it works ([source](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall16/cos402/lectures/402-lec4.pdf), slide 25):

---

Let $w$ be the separating hyperplane and $y \in \{-1, 1\}$.

Iteratively

1. Find vector $x_i$ for which $(w^{\bot} \cdot x_i)(y_i) \lt 0$
2. Add $x_i$ to $w$:

$$
w_{t+1}\leftarrow w_t + y_i x_i
$$

---

But imagine running the algorithm. Let's say we have a point $(2,2)$ with label $y = -1$. Let's start with a hyperplane $w_0 = (2, -1)$. What this algorithm will do is iteratively update $w_t$ by adding $-1 * (2, 2)$ or $(-2, -2)$ to each new hyperplane. What happens?

$$
w_0 = (2, -1)\\
w_1 = (0, -3)\\
w_2 = (-2, -5)\\
w_3 = (-4, -7)\\
w_4 = (-6, -9)\\
w_5 = (-8, -11)\\
...\\
w_n = (k, k-2)\\
$$

I've drawn these hyperplanes and $x = (2,2)$:

[image]

To my mind, the perceptron's hyperplane will keep moving closer and closer to $(2,2)$ without ever crossing that point. Thus, $(2,2)$ will forever be misclassified as $1$ instead of $-1$.

Am I misinterpreting this algorithm?

Comment: You have to look at the gradient descent method for minimizing an objective function (the problem of local minimas, the convexity). There is nothing more to understand for explaining why the ANN learning algorithm works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $w_1 = (0, -3)$, we have
$$
w_1^T x \cdot y = (-6) \cdot (-1) = 6 > 0
$$
Therefore, the perceptron algorithm will terminate with $w = (0, -3)$ and the resultant classifier would label $x$ as $\texttt{sign}(w^Tx) = -1$.

Comment: Oh, so $w_{1}^{\bot} = (-3,0)$, not $(3,0)$? I was visualizing the problem by rotating the hyperplane and its perpendicular together.

Comment: @gwg It is $w_1 = w_0 + x \cdot y = (2, -1) + (-2, -2) = (0, -3)$.

Comment: Right, I am convinced of this. But I was finding the perpendicular line visually, i.e. just drawing it pointing in the same direction as I rotated $w$. Is there an algorithm or definition for doing this correctly?

Comment: @gwg In this example, $w$ is sufficient to have an angle greater than $\pi / 2$ with $x$. It is not required the angle between $w$ and $x$ be $\pi / 2$ exactly.